# ValueFilter does not work in 2sxc in visual query

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a JSON result set which is like this

```
"Default": [
    {
      "PortalId": 0,
      "Price": 990000,
      "Featured": false,
      "Type": 1,
      "Bathrooms": 6,
      "Rooms": 5,
      "Volume": 0,
      "Area": 430,
      "CreatedDate": "2017-03-13T18:16:08.38Z",
      "ShowFrom": "2017-03-13T18:16:08.38Z",
      "ShowTill": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.997Z",
      "UserId": 2,
      "Kitchen": 1,
      "CityId": 46,
      "Code": "CA-799",
      "Verified": false,
      "Plot": 1234,
      "CityName": "Capdepera",
      "ImageName": "RV5",
      "ImagePath": "/Portals/0/RealEstateThumbs/20/RV5.jpg",
      "Id": 20,
      "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Title": null,
      "Modified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "_2sxcEditInformation": {
        "entityId": 20,
        "title": "(no title)",
        "isPublished": true
      }
    },
    {
      "PortalId": 0,
      "Price": 1750000,
      "Featured": false,
      "Type": 1,
      "Bathrooms": 6,
      "Rooms": 5,
      "Volume": 0,
      "Area": 360,
      "CreatedDate": "2017-03-10T10:25:42.647Z",
      "ShowFrom": "2017-03-10T10:25:42.647Z",
      "ShowTill": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.997Z",
      "UserId": 2,
      "Kitchen": 1,
      "CityId": 61,
      "Code": "ES-9337",
      "Verified": false,
      "Plot": 1234,
      "CityName": "Esporles",
      "ImageName": "RV6",
      "ImagePath": "/Portals/0/RealEstateThumbs/21/RV6.JPG",
      "Id": 21,
      "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Title": null,
      "Modified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "_2sxcEditInformation": {
        "entityId": 21,
        "title": "(no title)",
        "isPublished": true
      }
    }
```

When I add a ValueFilter to the Visual Query with a test parameter: [QueryString: Code]=SP

It does not filter on this Code value (in above example, those two results should not be returned).

What am I doing wrong?

The ValueFilter itself is defined as:

```
Attribute = Code
Value = [QueryString: Value]
Operator: begins
Take: all
```

It is the key to my solution.

Comment: can you add a screen shot of your visual query editor?  There may be other filters including records you don't want

Answer (score 1):

I believe the space in the token `[QueryString: Code]` is your problem - don't use spaces in tokens.